# Text to Decimal Converter Working but UI not getting updated

Tags: .net, vb.net, xaml, winrt-xaml, ivalueconverter

I wrote for string to decimal converter and it working fine, the binding is getting updated successfully, however, the GUI is not getting updated - this is for windows phone 8.1 - winrt if I am right.

Example: If I enter "0500" it is getting converted to Decimal value but GUI is not getting updated to 500.

Also, convert back is getting control and not the convert in Iconvert.

My Convert Code:

```
 Public Class DecimalConverter
            Implements IValueConverter

            Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
                Return value.ToString
            End Function

            Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
                Dim result As Decimal = 0
                Decimal.TryParse(value, result)
                Return result
            End Function
        End Class
```

Could you please correct me or advice where I went wrong.

Xaml Code:

```
xmlns:cn="using:MCPhone81.MCCommonCodes.Converters"
    <Page.Resources>
        <cn:VisibilityConverter x:Name="VisConvert"/>
        <cn:DecimalConverter x:Name="DecConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Obj.Amount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DecConverter}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="220" InputScope="Number" />
```

Output:
[image: Winrt Ui Output]

Edit:
Code for the binded class.

```
Public Class SimpleReceipt
            Inherits BaseClass
            Private _CollectionAmountValue As Decimal
            Property CollectionAmount As Decimal
                Get
                    Return _CollectionAmountValue
                End Get
                Set(value As Decimal)
                    If Not _CollectionAmountValue = value Then
                        _CollectionAmountValue = value
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("CollectionAmount")
                    End If
                End Set
            End Property
End Class
Public Class BaseClass
    Implements ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal PropertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Edit: Binding Data on UI

```
  Private Sub NavigationHelper_LoadState(sender As Object, e As LoadStateEventArgs) Handles _navigationHelper.LoadState
        ' TODO: Load the saved state of the page here.

        PivotControl.Title = "MCollector: Customer"
        If Not e.NavigationParameter = Nothing Then
            GetCustomer(e.NavigationParameter)
            GetBooks(e.NavigationParameter)
            GetLedgers(e.NavigationParameter)
            GetAllAccountsForCustomer(e.NavigationParameter)
        End If
    End Sub
 Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        RepObj = New MCPortable.Receipts.Classes.SimpleReceipt

        PreBinding()

        Me.DataContext = Me

    End Sub
Private Sub PreBinding()

    End Sub
 Private _RepObjValue As MCPortable.Receipts.Classes.SimpleReceipt
    Property RepObj As MCPortable.Receipts.Classes.SimpleReceipt
        Get
            Return _RepObjValue
        End Get
        Set(value As MCPortable.Receipts.Classes.SimpleReceipt)
            _RepObjValue = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RepObj")
            AddHandler RepObj.PropertyChanged, AddressOf RepObj_PropertyChanged
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Sub receiptbookscombobox_DataContextChanged(sender As FrameworkElement, args As DataContextChangedEventArgs) Handles receiptbookscombobox.DataContextChanged
        If receiptbookscombobox.Items.Count > 0 Then receiptbookscombobox.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub RepObj_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        SaveReceiptCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, why do your `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods both convert from `String` to `Decimal`?  The whole point is that the two methods convert in two different directions.  Your `Convert` method should be converting a `Decimal` to a `String` and `ConvertBack` goes from a `String` to a `Decimal`

Comment: Secondly, your `If` statement is pointless.  If `TryParse` fails then the output is set to `0D` so you may as well just return the output regardless.

Comment: @jmcilhinney :  Thank you, updated the question with corrected converter class as per my understanding now.

Comment: Have you implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel?

Comment: Also, how is the UI retrieving the value. It would be great if u can share with us more details about the data and the view model

Comment: Another thing to note, since your ValueConverter is initialized in the <Page.Resources> replace the x:Name with x:Key maybe this is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Rafael, I did try with Key instead of Name, it implements property change, but same result.  I provided by class behind. And just to clear - this is a windows phone 8.1 project.

Comment: ok thnx for the update. Now i just want to know how are you setting the obj.amount new value, are you entering it in a different textbox? and do u click a button to update it or do u just expect the textbox to update it when the text inside is changed?

Comment: @Refael: Thankyou. Directly Type in its textbox, the value is not edited anywhere, except the above said bindingbox with converter, No button etc is used since it is a twoway binding, since it a converter is in middle I think it should automatically get updated.